# Installation using setup.py is now impossible on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, setup.py, failed-installation, macos-big-sur

I have 2 of my projects that install perfectly fine on ubuntu, both require python3.8, both are installable using `python setup.py install` and I occasionally uninstall / install them from / to virtual environments as well as globally for testing purposes. Recently, all kinds of troubles and error messages started to occur not following any special event, I just woke up one day, and tried to install one of them, I got an error, then I tried the other and got another error. I will include both `setup.py` scripts and show the steps I follow **on macOS Big Sur 11.0** to reproduce the results, given that both install perfectly fine on Ubuntu with the same list of respective dependencies.

**Versions:**

```
python: 3.8.6
pip:    20.3.1
macOS:  11.0.1
```

**Project 1:**

`requirements.txt`

```
imagesize==1.2.0
numpy==1.18.5
pandas==1.1.4
seaborn==0.11.0
tensorflow==2.3.1
matplotlib==3.3.3
lxml==4.6.2
imgaug==0.4.0
tensorflow-addons==0.11.2
opencv-python-headless==4.4.0.46
imagecorruptions==1.1.2
configparser~=5.0.1
scipy==1.5.4
PyQt5==5.15.2
tabulate==0.8.7
ipykernel==5.3.4
```

`setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

install_requires = [dep.strip() for dep in open('requirements.txt')]

setup(
    name='project1',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='url',
    license='MIT',
    author='author',
    author_email='email@domain',
    description='description goes here',
    install_requires=install_requires,
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'some_entry_point',
        ],
    },
)
```

**Notes:**

- I will truncate logs for character limits.
- The attempts below are done within a virtualenv
- All kinds of problems do not occur if I just use `pip install -r requirements`
- Installation works perfectly fine on Ubuntu and used to work perfectly fine on macOS even after I upgraded to Big Sur, it just suddenly decided to never work again.
- python is installed using `brew install python@3.8`

**Attempt 1:**

```
virtualenv proj1
source proj1/bin/activate
python setup.py install
```

**Result:**

```
Searching for PyQt5==5.15.2
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/PyQt5/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz#sha256=372b08dc9321d1201e4690182697c5e7ffb2e0770e6b4a45519025134b12e4fc
Best match: PyQt5 5.15.2
Processing PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz
error: Couldn't find a setup script in /var/folders/hr/61r_7jcx2r3cnklwrr2zwbqw0000gn/T/easy_install-sl9y34mj/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz
```

**Attempt 2: (I install pyqt using pip)**

```
pip install pyqt5==5.15.2 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
No module named numpy.
```

**Attempt 3: (add `setup_requires=['numpy==1.18.5']` to `setup()`)**

```
python setup.py install
```

**Result:**

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

# Traceback goes here

RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring
```

**Attempt 4:**

I checked this [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13102) and there is nothing helpful yet so I manually install numpy and scipy:

```
pip install numpy==1.18.5 scipy # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
```

**Attempt 5:**

```
pip install scikit-build==0.11.1 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
error: Setup script exited with Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
```

**Attempt 6:**

I checked the issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-build/cmake-python-distributions/issues/76) and accordingly:

```
pip install cmake # success
python setup.py install
```

Opencv is being built, I'm not sure why or what triggered the build so I aborted and manually installed opencv using pip:

```
pip install opencv-python-headless==4.4.0.46 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow-addons==0.11.2')
```

**Attempt 7:**

```
pip install tensorflow-addons==0.11.2 # success
python setup.py install
```

Again lxml is being built, I don't know how or why, so I manually install it and:

```
pip install lxml==4.6.2 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
Running matplotlib-3.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/hr/61r_7jcx2r3cnklwrr2zwbqw0000gn/T/easy_install-q32mufo3/matplotlib-3.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-_js7sem9
UPDATING build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.8/matplotlib/_version.py
set build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.8/matplotlib/_version.py to '3.3.3'
error: Setup script exited with error: Failed to download FreeType. Please download one of ['https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/freetype/freetype2/2.6.1/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz', 'https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.6.1.tar.gz'] and extract it into build/freetype-2.6.1 at the top-level of the source repository.
```

**Attempt 8:**

```
pip install matplotlib==3.3.3 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:**

```
Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow==2.3.1')
```

**Attempt 9:(already more than 75% of  the requirements were already installed manually using pip in the previous attempts)**

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3.1 # success
python setup.py install # fail
```

**Result:(pandas fails to install)**

```
RuntimeError: Cannot cythonize without Cython installed.
```

**Attempt 10: (I manually install cython)**

```
pip install cython # success
python setup.py install
```

Again pandas for some reason is being built, so I manually install it and the list goes on ...
I think after this simple demonstration, I don't even need to replicate the steps of the second project however here are its requirements and I pretty much get a variation of the same problems shown above.

`requirements.txt` for project2

```
oauth2client==4.1.3
gcloud==0.18.3
pyarrow==2.0.0
requests==2.24.0
pandas==1.1.4
httplib2==0.15.0
TA-Lib==0.4.19
matplotlib==3.3.2
```

matplotlib fails first, followed by ta-lib (given that I run `brew install ta-lib` before then) and the list goes on ...

Comment: That's a lot. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example, if possible, but maybe in your case it's not possible. -- First thing, I somehow have doubts that this setup ever worked on mac os 11. It's fairly new, probably a lot of libraries are not compatible yet, or at least don't have wheels for this OS. -- Second thing, I also have doubts `python setup.py install` was ever able to install dependencies that are not _setuptools_ based from sdist, in your case that'd explain most of the failures. -- Really just use `python -m pip install ...`.

Comment: @sinoroc In fact a minimal reproducible example, if you have big sur you may run `setup.py` in a `virtualenv`  you will most probably see all kinds of troubles yourself. And it worked perfectly fine on macos big sur and it works on ubuntu with the same dependencies, I can't prove it though but I think it started to happen after python 3.8.6.2 update and I'm not sure. Regarding `pip install` Do you mean there is a way to install `setup.py` using `pip`?

Comment: Instead of `python setup.py install` do `python -m pip install .` -- Instead of `python setup.py develop` do `pip install --editable .`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `python setup.py install` do `python -m pip install .`.

Instead of `python setup.py develop` do `python -m pip install --editable .`.